# Python SFTP (pysftp) hangs when sending 31kb of data

Tags: python, pysftp

I am doing an upload to FTP server:

```
  chunks = math.ceil(size / BUFFER_SIZE)
  print('SFPTField: Uploading stream of length %s, chunks %d' % (size, chunks))

  for i in range(chunks):
        print('SFTPField: Writing chunk %d...' % (i + 1))
        b = buffer.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if len(b) == 0:
              break
        sftp_file.write(b)

        print('SFTPField: DONE for chunk %d...' % (i + 1))

  sftp_file.flush()
  sftp_file.close()
```

BUFFER_SIZE is set to 1024. The upload hangs infinitely during chunk 31. Usually only half of image jpg images get upload (that is, the top half of each).

Is this a reported bug in pysftp? How to solve it?

Comment: Do you succeed with a smaller image file? With a different image of the same size?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some limitations around 32767 (2^15-1). I suspect that the `sftp_file_write` is buffering the sent packet till it fills an internal buffer, and then tries to send it all at once.

Try adding a `flush()` in the loop, after each `write()` (in the loop).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks jcoppens. I have found a solution (thanks to another guy on StackOverflow).

```
channel = server.sftp_client.get_channel()
channel.lock.acquire()
channel.out_window_size += size
channel.out_buffer_cv.notifyAll()
channel.lock.release()
```

It works well for me so far.